# Error point sampling tool

Tags: qgis, python, error, sampling

I'm usig QGIS 1.8.0 and I did some interpolations. Now I want to do some sampling with the point sampling tool but I keep getting this error (I attach a picture of the error message). Does anybody knows why?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your field names in the attribute table contain unicode characters, and the tool cant handle that.

Try converting the field names to simple ascii chars (using for example the "table manager" plugin).

Comment: hi til_b, yes I'm using really simple names. I don't know why its happening :/ any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

I got it now, it was because indeed there were not-ascii characters in the title but in the fields inside the file. For next readers, do not use accents, commas or letters like "ñ" .....

Comment: I think it does answer the question (it was the same poster)

Comment: ?!?!?! I edited now, maybe it is more clear now....